# Different SPA on same firebase-hosting

Tags: firebase-hosting

I have firebase hosting and I want host 3 different SPA that uses same firestore and firebase hosting. And access them from different paths

```
mysite.com

1. Static Landing - with several predefined pages
paths: /, /contacts, /help, /partners

2. Main SPA with firestore access
paths: /posts, /map, /users

3. And CMS to control firestore  data.
paths: /admin
```

I'm using react, webpack for my SPA.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution Firebase Multi-site [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/one-project-multiple-sites-plus-boost.html)